Proving $f + c = O(f)$ doesn't always hold- where is my mistake?
I seem to have proved the following statement false: that for any function $f : \mathbb{Z}^{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and any $c \in \mathbb{R}, f +c = O(f)$, where for any $2$ functions $f : \mathbb{Z}^{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $g : \mathbb{Z}^{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$, $f = O(g)\iff \exists c \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \forall x \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}f(x) \le c \cdot g(x)$. I assume that there is a mistake in my proof, as in my earlier computer science courses I was told, in informal terms, that we can eliminate all constants in the function $f$, and the ensuing function $g$ would be such that $f = O(g)$. Here is my proof:
If $f+c = O(f)$ for any function $f : \mathbb{Z}^{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and any $c \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\exists k \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \forall x \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}f(x) + c \le k \cdot f(x)$. Subtracting $f(x)$ from both sides of the inequality, we have that $\exists k \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \forall x \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}c \le (k-1) \cdot f(x)$. However, because $c$ was any real number, if $c$ was positive, and if $f$ gets arbitrarily small, such as $f(x) = \frac 1 x$, it is impossible for the inequality to hold- as $(k-1) \cdot f(x)$ gets arbitrarily small here, so it cannot be forever bigger than or equal to some positive constant $c$. This contradicts our assumption, therefore disproving it.
So where was my mistake in my proof?

Let $f = 0$ and $c = 1$.  Clearly $1 \not\in O(0)$.  The informal statement "we can eliminate all constants in the function $f$" would be better phrased "we can eliminate all (eventually) bounded multipliers and terms that are (eventually) insignificant compared to $f$".  Here we notice that $1$ is never insignificant compared to $f = 0$.

Computer Science courses often only talk about functions that grow with the size of their inputs. That may have been a hidden assumption on the part of whoever told you that you can eliminate constants.

Also, people are notoriously very sloppy when it comes to using big-O notation

Your proof is correct. To simplify it you can just give the counterexample you stated: Taking $f(x)=1/x$, and $c=1$, there is no $k$ such that $f(x)+c < kf(x)$ for all $x$.
The statement as given does hold if $f(x) = \Omega(1)$.
